# Unity "Dash Home" icon completely missing

Tags: unity

In 11.10 the icon for the "dash home" button is missing, the generic question mark icon shows.

How do I fix this?  It happened after I installed and uninstalled an icon theme in synaptic (Breathe).

Answer (score 1):

Undo your last step.

It is most likely that the 'dash home' icon is missing in the theme you have chosen.